# Align Forms correctly

Tags: html, css, forms

I have this form:

```
<form action="insertar-modelo.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <table>


    <tr><td class=Forms>ICAO: <input type="text" value="" name="ICAO" /><br/><br/></td</tr>

    <tr><td class=Forms>Name: <input type="text" value="Airbus A320" name="nombre" /><br/><br/></td></tr>
    <tr><td class=Forms>Price: <input maxlength="9" value="1000000" type="text" name="precio" /> €<br/><br/></td></tr>

    <tr><td class=Forms>Number Classes: <select name="numberclasses" id="numberclasses" onchange="callAjax()">
        <option>Select Number of Classes</option>
        <?php
        echo'<option value="1">One</option>';
        echo'<option value="2">Two</option>';
        echo'<option value="3">Three</option>';

        ?>
    </select><br/><br/></td></tr>


    <tr><td class=Forms>First Class: <input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="classes1" /><br/><br/></td></tr>
    <tr><td class=Forms>Bussines Class: <input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="classes2" /><br/><br/></td></tr>
    <tr><td class=Forms>Economy Class: <input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="classses" /><br/><br/></td></tr>

    <tr><td class=Forms>Capacidad: <input maxlength="3" value="150" type="text" name="pax" /> pasajeros<br/><br/></td></tr>
    </table><br />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Insertar"/>
    </form>
```

And the CSS class Forms is:

```
td.Forms { 


    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 10px;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The boxes start when the title finish and I want the boxes start all in the same part. I think the idea is see the titles in one colum and the boxes in other, like this http://i48.tinypic.com/2nbd2m8.png, but I have this http://i49.tinypic.com/1exb80.png

Comment: can you update the markup? if so, consider this: http://formee.org/

Comment: You're using php to echo simple HTML ? Try to use a fixed width to your td-s.

Comment: why are we using tables to code an html form? One can argue forms to be tabular but I digress; pure css (no tables) give you more flexibility - especially when it comes to adding form elements that expand past a typical rectangle assumed by a table cell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add extra cells (`<td>`) for your input fields so that they all start on the same position.  Additionally you may want to define a width to ensure that you have enough space between one cell and another on a row.  I defined it to all `<td>`'s by adding `width: 200px;` to your td.Forms.  Lastly to give spacing between rows I added:

```
td {
  padding: 10px 0;   
}
```

Which adds 10px padding to the top and bottom of every cell.

Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yDUdL/1/) to see the code in action.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct html markup (assuming you're going to use table layout for this). [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vm69v/).

```
<form action="insertar-modelo.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <table>


    <tr>
        <td class=Forms>ICAO:</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" name="ICAO" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class=Forms>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="Airbus A320" name="nombre" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class=Forms>Price:</td>
        <td><input maxlength="9" value="1000000" type="text" name="precio" /> €</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class=Forms>Number Classes:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="numberclasses" id="numberclasses" onchange="callAjax()">
            <option>Select Number of Classes</option>
            <?php
            echo'<option value="1">One</option>';
            echo'<option value="2">Two</option>';
            echo'<option value="3">Three</option>';
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class=Forms>First Class:</td>
        <td><input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="classes1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class=Forms>Bussines Class:</td>
        <td><input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="classes2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class=Forms>Economy Class:</td>
        <td><input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="classses" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class=Forms>Capacidad:</td>
        <td><input maxlength="3" value="150" type="text" name="pax" /> pasajeros</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Insertar"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to him if you provided an explanation on your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give you the answer - but first I want to explain some semantics and how one can properly code a form WITHOUT using tables.

Html form have been around since the inception of html. You will be amazed how many html form elements ARE NOT utilized when they simply exist to help you code properly semantic html. Proper semantic html means:

1) Your code is accessible to text viewers such as Google search engine and browsers used by blind people
2) Fulfills federal law (US laws require school/government websites to be accessible)
3) Will make it easier for you to code the backend (php) in the long run.

A form at its barebones should include:

```
<form>
 <fieldset>
   <div>
     <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
     <input type="textbox" name="first_name" id="first-name" value="" />
   </div>
   <div>
     <label for="gender_selection">Gender</label>
     <select name="gender" id="gender_selection">
       <option value="male">Male</option>
       <option value="female">Female</option>
     </select>
   </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

- You must have a `fieldset` tag for each `form` tag.
- `label` tag is used to define what the form element stands for. THIS IS WHAT tells a text viewer what each form element stands for! Sure you can do without but why when this tag was created for exactly that purpose.
- The div tags will allow you to easily style errors/corrections needed.

CSS

```
form div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
form div label {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}
form div input, form div select {
  float: left;
  width: 220px;
}
```

Simple css (not tested) to mimic your tabular forms with the added advantage of not using tables, being accessible, and using proper html.

Now if a user made an error with in let us say `first name` we simply add class `.error` to that div:

```
   <div class="error">
     <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
     <input type="textbox" name="first_name" id="first-name" value="" />
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.error label {
  color: red;
}
div.error input {
  border: red;
  color: red;
}
```

ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION:

Your html form "label" elements do not have a fixed width. Add a fixed width by either adding an extra `<td>` column or using the code I provided above.

Hopefully this post will help you for the future.